# PHP search msql table to find the most popular field

Tags: php, mysql, select

This is a little hard to explain, so i will make an example.

mysql table books

books

```
firstname |lastname |state |favbook  
john      |doe      | WA   |bookname1
john      |doe      | WA   |bookname2
john      |doe      | WA   |bookname3
john      |doe      | WA   |bookname1
```

I have users who are able to enter names of books.
How can i search to find the most popular book without knowing what the book it called.

```
$sql4 = "SELECT favbook FROM books WHERE favbook!='' ORDER BY start ASC";
$query4 = mysqli_query($database, $sql4)
```

There are just way to many books possible, is there a way i can find duplicates and just display the one with the highest amount of duplicates?

If someone knows a better way to ask please let me know or edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have a look at `COUNT`and `GROUP BY` in the [documentation on counting rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/counting-rows.html).

`SELECT favbook, COUNT(*) FROM books GROUP BY favbook` should give you a list of  how often each book is in your table.

This is not the complete answer to your question but I'm sure you will figure out how to go on from there. If not add a comment to my answer :)

Comment: This is what i wanted, i can not believe i forgot about count, i used it for friends.  Thank you so much.  I ,knew i was forgetting something!